# Excel VBA Embed Individual Images to List of Email Contacts

Tags: vba, excel, email, automation

I have been assigned to send out Christmas greetings that have been customized to specific customers. However, these greetings are in the 100's and doing it automatically would save me hours - and these greetings are done every year!

In Excel, the customer names are listed in column A, the individual emails in column B, and the path to the individual customized greeting file in column C.

What I have currently found is a VBA code that offers me the option to attach (but not embed) these files through their paths to the individual emails.

Might anyone explain to me and/or demonstrate how to embed the attached files that are found through column C ?

Thank you very much!

What I have now is the following:

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Merry Christmas!"
                .Body = "Merry Christmas!"

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value, olByValue, 0
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you just need to set filecell to be cell.offset(0,1)

Comment: @Nat Excuse my stupidity, but where does it go? If it is not too demanding, might I ask you to write it into the code, so that I can copy it. (This is my first time using VBA).

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I tagged you wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do using HTML email, something like

```
Set o = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
o.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
o.HTMLBody = "<img src='C:\Users\Pictures\a1.png'>"
o.Display
```

Comment: Thank you, but where does this fit into the code I wrote above?